# Is there a safe way to auto add a dynamic IP to /etc/hosts.allow file?

Tags: bash, ssh, ip

(I was forwarded from SO to here for help, so hopefully this is the correct section)

Is there a way to automatically add 2 or 3 dynamic IP's to the "/etc/hosts.allow" file on a CentOS 7 server?

I want to make this server's SSH more secure, other than relying on Fail2Ban and ipset for several countries. Though the combination of the last two should make things more secure, but I wanted to know if it was possible to have some kind of script which checks the IP's of 2 or 3 computers and adds them to "/etc/hosts.allow"

And also removing the previous entries? I am guessing that last part can be achieved by giving the IP's a name like #Dynamic IP James computer, #Dynamic IP Peter and so on.

The check should be run every 5 or 10 minutes. Though the IP normally does not change, but you never know and this server should be reachable by any of us (always).

Maybe someone has an intelligent idea or solution to achieve the above? Or maybe it's not possible at all? Or should I stick with Fail2Ban and ipset only?

Sidenote; I didn't know which tags I had to use for this question, so sorry if I used the wrong ones.

Comment: Have you tried using a dynamic DNS service such as duckdns.org?

Comment: If the address are "dynamic", how do you determine that they are trustable?

Comment: Because it's our IP's? Therefor they are trustworthy? That's why I need some sort of tool, script, which can check my IP. Yes, I know Dynamic DNS services, however I have no clue on how to use that on a Linux server in combination with /etc/host.allow.

Comment: If these are "your IPs" they can't be that dynamic (all in the same handful or ranges)?

Comment: It's our dynamic IP's at the office. They can change sometimes, therefor we want to limit access to our servers for these IP's. There must be some script which fetches your current IP and adds them to /etc/hosts.allow file, right? Same with DDNS sevices I use (for example) on my NAS. There must be something similar for servers, so it adds it to the list of allowed IP's (and removing the old ones if possible).